# Can I get a partial view with a query in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to grab a partial view with a querystring?

Such as `<%Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial/5")%>`?

Comment: You're confusing the model with the URL here. What you want to do is pass a model representing "5" as data when rendering your partial view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial", 5)%>
```

In Partial View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<int>" %>

<%= Model.ToString() %>
```